# Converting List into Dictionary of Sorted Tuples

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've used the following approach many times to generate a list of tuples from the contents of a dictionary:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items())
```

In this case, the keys are different types of ways a patient can leave the emergency department, and the values are counts of those types. Now, I wanted to sort this data based on the second item in each of the tuples, so I tried this:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items()).sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

To my surprise, when I ran the code, I found that dispositions had been set to None. I tried breaking it into two parts, as follows:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items())
dispositions.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This works! I got my list of sorted tuples. So, I've already solved my problem, but I want to know why the first option didn't work so that I can be a better person (better programmers are better people). Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Although your questions is answered below, please note that StackOverflow is for posting non-working code/seeking help with the solution. For the code that works, but you would like an improvement or additional explanation, please use CodeReview website https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is also part of StackExchange network. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

`list.sort` does not return anything. So this:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items()).sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

sets `dispositions` to `None`.

`sorted` on the other hand returns a new list. So you would use:

```
dispositions = sorted(dispositions.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Which will set `dispositions` to a sorted list of tuples.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` function doesn't work like you might think. It does not return a sorted list, it directly modifies the list so it's sorted.

For instance, say you have this code:

```
a = [0, 2, 1]
a.sort()
```

`a` will now be changed `[0, 1, 2]`. Had I used `a = a.sort()` rather than just `a.sort()`, it would have been set to `None`.

This:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items()).sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

functions the same as this:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items())
dispositions = dispositions.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Which sets `dispositions` to the returned value from `sort`, which is `None`.

On the other hand, this:

```
dispositions = list(dispositions.items())
dispositions.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

is not setting `dispositions` to the value of `sort`, it's simply calling the `sort` function on `dispositions`, which causes the list to be sorted as intended.

Comment: That also makes sense. Thank you also.